# Looking for an e-commerce backend dataset

Tags: data-request, business

Does anybody know of a data set that has been open sourced that contains significant (or all) the tables from and e-commerce backend. Examples could include:

1. A small store (like a pet store)
2. A non-profit's membership management system
3. A small restaurant's backend